# Proof of Markov Chain property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chain

Suppose that $X_n$ is a Markov Chain.Then for $m,n \in N$ such that $m<n$
$Pr[X_n=j_n|X_m=j_m,X_{m-1}=j_{m-1},...=X_0=j_0]=Pr[X_n=j_n|X_m=j_m]$

When proving for n=3,m=1 case we have to show that $Pr[X_3=j_3|X_1=j_1,X_0=j_0]=Pr[X_3=j_3|X_1=j_1] $

I don't understand the following step.

$Pr[X_3=j_3|X_1=j_1 and X_0=j_0]=  
\sum_{j_2}Pr[(X_3=j_3)\cap (X_2=j_2)|(X_1=j_1)\cap(X_0=j_0)]$
I don't understand how this $j_2$ terms are brought in and why?

Comment: Is this self-study? You should add the tag then.

Answer (score 0):

you'd use [law of total probability.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$Pr(A)=\sum\limits_nPr(A\cap B_n)$

$A=Pr[X_3=j_3|X_1=j_1 and X_0=j_0],~B=(X_2=j_2),~n=j_2$